# Which tag should be used for restoring backups?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Apparently we have two almost equally used tags that are being used mostly for the same purpose.  Lets pick one, merge, and setup an alias.  I like the `backup-restoration` choice a bit more, because it is more descriptive, but it is possible there are things in `restore` that aren't about restoring for a backup.

- [backup-restoration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/backup-restoration) x248
- [restore](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/restore) x234

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Even if there are questions in [restore] that are not related to backups, the tag excerpt is unambiguous:</strike> (Actually, I interpreted the tag dates wrong. The tag has been around for five years, but the tag wiki was only applied in 2012.)

This has been the description of [restore](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/restore) for the last three years:

> Returning data from a backup to its original location or to its successor.

I'm inclined to say that the intended use of this tag has been unambiguous for the majority of its lifetime, barring the usual case where someone types `restore whatever` into the list of tags. Aliasing the tag to [backup-restoration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/backup-restoration) seems to make sense and would prevent further creep of unintended usage.

Comment: I don't feel really strongly one way or the other.  If the description has been good over 3 years then restore may be the better choice.  I just really want to have a single tag.

Comment: Something to consider:  Restore isn't clear.  Backup-Restoration is perfectly clear.  System Restoration on Windows is not equitable to Backup Restoration (Although there are many parallels).